# Rake caches rspec tests or what?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

When I run rspec tests via rake task I get

```
1) Whois::Record::Parser::WhoisUa status_available.expected#created_on 
 Failure/Error: lambda { @parser.created_on }.should raise_error(Whois::PropertyNotSupported)
```

But my `status_available_spec.rb` looks like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8

# This file is autogenerated. Do not edit it manually.
# If you want change the content of this file, edit
#
#   /spec/fixtures/responses/whois.ua/status_available.expected
#
# and regenerate the tests with the following rake task
#
#   $ rake spec:generate
#

require 'spec_helper'
require 'whois/record/parser/whois.ua.rb'

describe Whois::Record::Parser::WhoisUa, "status_available.expected" do

  before(:each) do
    file = fixture("responses", "whois.ua/status_available.txt")
    part = Whois::Record::Part.new(:body => File.read(file))
    @parser = klass.new(part)
  end

  describe "#status" do
    it do
      @parser.status.should == :available
    end
  end
  describe "#available?" do
    it do
      @parser.available?.should == true
    end
  end
  describe "#registered?" do
    it do
      @parser.registered?.should == false
    end
  end
  describe "#created_on" do
    it do
      @parser.created_on.should == nil
    end
  end
  describe "#updated_on" do
    it do
      @parser.updated_on.should == nil
    end
  end
  describe "#expires_on" do
    it do
      @parser.expires_on.should == nil
    end
  end
  describe "#nameservers" do
    it do
      @parser.nameservers.should be_a(Array)
      @parser.nameservers.should == []
    end
  end
end
```

and as you can see there is no `.should raise_error(Whois::PropertyNotSupported)` instead it was changed to `.should == nil`.

Is rake caching that stuff or what?

Comment: Is a test server like spork running in the background?

Comment: @Stefan no, I'm not using any servers.

Comment: Have you renamed the file on disk, but forgotten to close the file in your editor?  This catches me out on occasion, where I actually save a file in Vim that I've renamed on disk, effectively creating duplicates that are out of sync.